# Insert using PHP shows up as a download instead of executing

Tags: php, html, insert, execute

Sorry if this already exists, but I couldn't find this anywhere.

I am trying to insert information from a form into a table called "instest" inside a database called "test". The columns inside the "instest" table are "firstName", "lastName", and "age".

The problem is that every time click on the submit button it either shows up as a download (IE) or the code shows up (Opera), instead of the code actually executing.

Here is the code:

```html
/* TestInsert.php */

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="Insert.php" method="post">
        Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" />
        Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
        Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```php
/* Insert.php */

<?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root@localhost"); //No password
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("test", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO instest (firstName, lastName, age)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: Is there also a beginning `<?` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a `value="submit"`browsers prefer proper html

Comment: It's not interpreting it as PHP, so either it **CAN'T** or it **ISN'T**. Seeing as you have the right extension and markup, and presuming you didn't mess around with the server settings, I'd say your server just doesn't support it.

Comment: The server supports PHP. It's a WAMP server. The "<?php" is not missing. It was a formatting mistake when I posted the question.

Comment: If its wamp than most likely you haven't set it up properly.  Is Apache running? Is web hosting enabled on system prerences? And you opening it from localhost?

Comment: Yes I have used PHP before through DreamWeaver, but now I'm doing it from scratch in notepad++. It's a localhost.

Comment: If its WAMP that most likely means you haven't set it up right

Comment: It's weird that it wouldn't be set up wrong because I can go into dream weaver and access the database, but not from notepad++.

Comment: So then notepad isn't configured properly. Google notepad ++ and wamp.  Bound to find st

Comment: Well, I googled notepad++ and wamp and didn't find all that much. I just uninstalled wamp and deleted all the wamp files and then reinstalled it. It just worked after that. I'm not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you simply forgot to open the PHP tags in `Insert.php` using either `<?php` or `<?` (the former being the most compatible, and therefore preferable, version).

Comment: I edited that. It was a formatting mistake when I was trying to post the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error with this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO instest (firstName, lastName, age)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";
```

Try changing it to this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO instest (firstName, lastName, age)
VALUES
('". $_POST[firstname] ."','". $_POST[lastname] ."','". $_POST[age] ."')";
```

I know you can have variables inside "" (I personally think its bad practice and slower)  I think you will run into constant problems with the post var and how php interprets that.

You should turn on error_reporting as it would reflect that.

Comment: Oh also, it is extremely bad practice to not escape posted variables when inserting data into the database.